# Saving list in csv file

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains lists as shown

```
dfg <- structure(list(a = list(c("BD", "AS", "MS", 
                                                 "CMO")), b = list(list(width = 757.5, height = 500L))), row.names = "x1", class = "data.frame")
```

But I am unable to save this in csv fie

```
write.csv(dfg, "d.csv")
Error in write.table(dfg, "d.csv", col.names = NA, sep = ",", dec = ".",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

Is there a way to save this?

Comment: You can't save nested lists like this in a CSV file. CSV files are just for simple rectangular data. I mean, you could convert that column to a character representation, but then you'd have to parse specially when you read it in. There's no csv reader that will automatically parse complex objects like that (since they aren't expected to be there in the first place.) Maybe consider a different file format like RDS which can preserve R objects.

Comment: To keep the data structure, use [`saveRDS`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) instead.